# Convergence according to $n$th-term test

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

According to the $n$th-term test for divergence, a series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ diverges if $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \neq 0$.

But I don't actually get it.

I thought that if I have
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n = C
$$
then the series $\sum_{n=1}^n a_n$ converges against $C$? Isn't this correct?

So I thought that if
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = C
$$
where $C$ also can be $0$, the value of the series is $C$? Is this correct?

I have maybe misunderstood something about convergence of series.

Comment: Not really, think of the sequence $1,1,1,1,1,...$ which converges to $1$ but the series $1+1+1+1+...$ diverges.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you aren't confusing the $a_n$'s, which you are summing up, with the sequence of partial sums, $a_1$, $a_1+a_2$, $a_1+a_2+a_3$, etc.

Indeed, if the series is convergent, then the *sequence* of partial sums converges to some limit. But if $a_n$ doesn't go to $0$ for large $n$, then you are summing up an infinite number terms who are either constant and non-zero, or even increasing. Thus the infinite sum will "blow up."

Comment: What you are saying is correct but probably you should think of another sentence for "you are summing up an infinite number of non-zero terms, so the series can't converge" because this is incorrect.

Comment: Good point; edited